# How do I install a specific Focal version like 245.4-4ubuntu3.10?

Tags: software-installation, docker

I am currently using Docker to install Ubuntu `20.04` like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
```

I ran some security audit and there are a few vulnerabilities and it says they are fixed in version

```
245.4-4ubuntu3.10
```

and my current installed version it says is:

```
245.4-4ubuntu3.7
```

Are these tags for nightly builds?   I am just referencing ubuntu 20.04 as you can see so curious as to how I would install this specific version of  `245.4-4ubuntu3.10` using Docker.

Comment: @pLumo Yes it is a libsystemd0 issue: CVE-2021-33910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version number is not from Ubuntu itself, but from one of its packages. They have the `ubuntu` name in it as they are specifically built for Ubuntu possibly with backports.

Actually, this seems to be `systemd`.

Current version in repos is `245.4-4ubuntu3.11`, so you could just run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y` after you started your container or during build in your `Dockerfile`.

Not sure, why the ubuntu docker image is outdated... Doucker hub says "Last pushed 13 days ago", which is before the fix [came to Ubuntu at "Tue, 20 Jul 2021 07:39:51 -0400"](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/245.4-4ubuntu3.10).

Comment: For changelog see https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.11/changelog

Comment: For CVEs, an easy reference is also https://ubuntu.com/security/cve-2021-33910